# Does number of charging batteries matter

Tags: rimworld

Let's say I have excess of 1000 W and I have empty batteries.

**Am I going to store the same amount of power if I have 5 or 10 batteries?** Let's say that we do not fulfill the batteries in some time.

Aka does it mean that lower number of batteries is charging faster than larger number but **in the end I am going to get the same amount of stored power?**

Example of battery info:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will store the same amount of power, the power is equally distributed between all the batteries in this circuit that aren't full yet. You won't store any faster or slower depending on the number of batteries as it only depends on the excess W you have (the more watt, the faster it charges)

Comment: That being said, batteries with lower efficiency will of course incur more power loss. I forget if it's one of my mods or not but the upgraded batteries have higher efficiency.

Comment: There is only one type of battery in Rimworld at the time i write this, and you are right about the efficiency, if your output is 1000W, you will only store 500W